# Rust, trait bound Option is not defined using process::Command

Tags: rust

First of all, I know there is a package for git am making a program to practice Rust and I get stacked. The idea (from now) is to look at the current branch and make a checkout (switch). Don't mind about making a checkout to the actual branch, as I said, and practicing with Rust.

This is the piece of code:

```rust
fn get_current_branch() {
    let current_branch = Command::new("git")
        .arg("rev-parse")
        .arg("--abbrev-ref")
        .arg("HEAD")
        .output()
        .expect("Can't retrieve the current branch");
    let current: String = String::from_utf8(current_branch.stdout).unwrap().to_string();
    Command::new("git")
        .arg("checkout")
        .arg(current.pop())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Can't change branch");
}
```

The problem is, at the line when doing `pop()` it show an error:

> "the trait bound `std::option::Option<char>: std::convert::AsRef<std::ffi::OsStr>` is not satisfied"

I looked at different possible answer but nothings works.

Thanks for the help, ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use the whole branch, and not just the first character, which is what `pop` will give you. So, just use `current` or `current.trim()` if there's a newline afterwards that you want to get rid of.